# calling Web Service Method Through wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, jboss

I have a web application which calls the web service methods through wsdl. The wsdl url is successfully browsed through web browser but get following exception while calling webservice through web application deployed in jboss server.

```
Stacktrace:
    Org. apache. jasper. servlet. JspServletWrapper. handleJspException (JspServletWrapper.java: 504)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)


root cause 
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 403: Forbidden
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:222)
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:179)
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
    com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
    com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:157)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: 403 error comes when you are not authorized to access url/link.. check your link properly..

Comment: The link is correct. The link is browsed through the browser.

Comment: No one face this type of error? I need quick solution. Please Help me.

Comment: I had used Soap library (android), I don't know what code u r implementing.. Put or code for more details... YOu might have passing wrong or less parameters to access.